# Click events won't respond after searching contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

Click events won't respond after searching contents.
I have created search functionality that searches contents of array values of the `title`, or `body`.
Also there is an option to press on the title and then the body dropdowns, but after searching, the click events won't respond. I think that is because the click's functionality is on the mounted method, but tried to replace that to method, but it doesn't work properly.

HTML:

```
<div class="block faq-block">
   <div v-for="contents in filteredContents" class="col-sm-12 faq-elem">
      <div class="faq-title">
       <div>{{contents.title}}</div>
       <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
       <i class="fa fa-minus d-none"></i>
     </div>
     <p>{{contents.body}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
export default {
    props: [],
    data: () => ({
        saving: false,
        search: '',
contents: [
   {title: 'lorem ipsum',
    body: 'lorem ipsum'},
   {title: 'lorem ipsum',
    body: 'lorem ipsum'},
]
}),
computed:
        {
         filteredContents: function () {
         var self = this;
         return this.contents.filter(function (cont) {
         return cont.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0 
         || cont.body.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
         });
     }
 },
mounted() {
        $('.faq-elem .faq-title').click(function (e) {
            $(this).next('p').slideToggle();

            let plus = $(this).find('.fa-plus');
            let minus = $(this).find('.fa-minus');

            if (plus.hasClass('d-none')) {
                plus.removeClass('d-none');
                minus.addClass('d-none');
            } else {
                plus.addClass('d-none');
                minus.removeClass('d-none');
            }
        });
```

Example:
[image]
[image]

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: can you also share where you implement the click functionality?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include. Updated the question.